# The prefered Convert chrome app to a windows application

Tags: cordova, google-chrome-app, node-webkit

What is the best way to convert a Chrome app to a standalone app?
I have created a beautiful Chrome app that I planned to convert into a mobile app using cordova phone gap and now I suddenly was requested for a standalone windows app for none chrome user.

Comment: You don't need to use Chrome to use a Chrome App. Install Chrome but keep your browser of choice. Think of Chrome in this case as Java's JRE or Adobe Air: it's just a runtime; the fact that it could also be a browser is irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want to distribute the app to others.  If you just want it for yourself, sowbug's suggestion  above is likely good enough for you.  At the basic level, a chrome app is a compressed file containing HTML, CSS, and JavaScript.  You can build the same app and either put it on a server, or put it on the user's disk, and have the user double click the top level HTML file.  You could even make an installer for it with a desktop shortcut or start menu item on windows, or app launcher icon on Mac.

Now, if you are using chrome APIs (like chrome.notoficiations, for example), there is generally no substitute for them.  If you can write your app without them, then you don't need to do much, but if your app needs them to do its job, there may not be much you can do until the APIs are standardized and in all browsers in the further future.  If not, delivering your app as a chrome app may be the best you can do, and your users can do as sowbug suggests and use chrome as just an App runtime even if they normally use a different browser.